# node.js : build an sql query with specific conditions through function arguments

Tags: mysql, node.js

let me get to the code straight away

in my routes.js

```
var dashboard_report = require('./controllers/dash_rep');
app.post('/dashboard_report', dashboard_report.get_dash_report);
```

in controllers/dash_rep.js

```
var dcn_db = require('../connect/database');
var data_model = require('../models/dash_rep.js');
exports.get_dash_report = function(req, res){
  dcn_db.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(!req.body.opid){
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    var opid = req.body.opid;
    connection.query(data_model.dash_report(req.body),opid, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err) {
        console.log('Error while performing Query. ' + err); //error respose
        return res.json({ error : "true"})
        }else{
          return res.json({ error : "false", data : rows}); //parse result to json instantly
        }
    });
    connection.release();
  });
};
```

in models/dash_rep.js

```
module.exports = {
  dash_report: function(req){
    var dash_data = 'SELECT * FROM dcn_payments p '
                  +'LEFT JOIN lineman l ON l.lnId = p.lnId '
                  +'LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.cId = p.cId '
                  +'LEFT JOIN areas a on a.areaId = c.areaId '
                  +'WHERE p.opId = 1 ';
    if(parseInt(req.area,10) > 0){
      dash_data += " AND c.areaId = "+req.area;
    }
    if(parseInt(req.status,10) > -1){
      dash_data += " AND p.status = "+req.status;
    }
    if(parseInt(req.state,10) > -1){
      dash_data += " AND c.state = "+req.state;
    }
    if(parseInt(req.lnId,10) > 0){
      dash_data += " AND p.lnId = "+req.lnId;
    }
    if(parseInt(req.duration,10) > -1){
      dash_data += " AND "+req.duration;
    }
    dash_data += " ORDER BY p.time ASC, p.status ASC ";
    return dash_data;
  }
}
```

Now the error I am getting is

```
C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\newrelic\lib\transaction\tracer\index.js:172
      throw err
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at C:\dcntvnodeapi\controllers\dash_rep.js:9:15
    at wrapped (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\newrelic\lib\transaction\tracer\index.js:157:28)
    at getConnectionCallback (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\newrelic\lib\instrumentation\mysql.js:162:11)
    at Handshake.onConnect (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:54:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:358:14)
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:384:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Socket.wrapped (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\newrelic\lib\transaction\tracer\index.js:157:28)
    at Socket.wrappedEmit [as emit] (C:\dcntvnodeapi\node_modules\newrelic\lib\transaction\tracer\index.js:201:46)
8 Nov 18:23:10 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Quoting error *at C:\dcntvnodeapi\controllers\dash_rep.js:9:15*
Which is line `connection.query(data_model.dash_report(req.body),opid, function(err, rows, fields) {`

now from what i understand it is not getting the query itself but if the query is called and saved in another variable it is building the correct query but that variable when used inside connection.query() is again giving the same error.

I believe it has something to do with ASYNC Nature of node.js but I do not know the solution.

**UPDATE:**

database.js file

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.pool = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dxxxxxt',
  password : 'xxxxxxx',
  database : 'xxxxxxx'
});
```

Comment: The error message `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` means that *connection* is undefined. Check the *err* argument you are getting before trying to access the connection argument. I think you will find error information there.

Comment: Could you share your database.js (without revealing passwords of course)? Notably the code where you initialise your pool with something like `mysql.createPool`.

Comment: this is database/database.js file
`var mysql = require('mysql');
exports.pool = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dcn',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'db'
});`

Comment: found the error... there was some port related error in my sql connection
thanks @trincot

Comment: Welcome, glad you found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to suggestion by @trincot 
to find the error one should do

```
dcn_db.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
   console.log(err);
   ....
});
```

for me the error was related to the mysql port